# Daily budget for backpacking in South America

Tags: budget, backpacking, south-america

I'm going backpacking in South America for 4 months (Jan-Apr 2019) and I will pass through Argentina, Chile, Bolivia, Peru, Ecuador and Colombia.

Has anyone been backpacking on a budget in these countries and can give me a daily/weekly/monthly budget for it?

Comment: Welcome to TSE. I'm afraid as currently framed, your question is primarily a matter of opinion, and will likely be closed as such. Everyone has different standards, priorities, tastes, lifestyles, and so on and you've listed a series of large countries which are not only very different from one another, but which vary enormously internally between rural and urban, central and provincial, and so on. Please take the site [tour] and review the [help] and see if you can narrow the scope to fit the guidelines.